# Как оформить программу?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Написал консольную программу на чистом СИ в среде MCVS 2013. В проекте указал консольное приложение, поставив галку на пустая программа. Мне нужно сдать эту программу как готовый продукт для курсача(я школьник, буду защищать работу демонстрируя программу).

1. Как оформить программу в который продукт(принёс на флешке, ввел данные, запустил - опа работает). Что бы смотрелось красиво(т.е. без системной информации).
2. Можно ли сделать её кроссплатформенной(что бы один и тот же экземпляр работал на всех осях)?
3. Меня просят написать системные требования. Что писать к программе, которая всего в 400 строк кода, работает секунд 20-30?

Ребят, никогда ранее не делал такого, прошу без подколов.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если в MCVS в режиме отладки на intel i-7 ввести нереально большие числа, то программа потребляет 7-10% ЦП и  1-1,5 мб ОЗУ.
  
PS под нереально большими числами я подразумеваю числа в 100-200 раз более реальных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Просто приносите исполняемый файл для той платформы (или платформ), на которой предполагается запускать программу. Не забывайте про зависимости: проверьте на другом компьютере или в виртуальной машине, не требует ли ваше приложение библиотек Visual Studio.
2. Не получится. Пиши вы на Java или каком-нибудь интерпретируемом языке (Python, например), тоакой фокус мог бы прокатить, но C так не может, так как форматы исполняемых файлов на разных платформах разные. Поэтому, если нужна кроссплатформенность, то см. п. 1: приносим исполняемые файлы для всех платформ, где предполагается запуск программы. А для особых эстетов можно принести исходники и makefile, пусть сами собирают под свою платформу. Отдельно обращаю ваше внимание на то, что приложение будет компилироваться на разных платформах только если вы не используете какие-то платформо-зависимые функции (например, приложение, использующее WinAPI не соберётся под Linux). К тому же, стоит помнить про разрядность `int`'ов на разных архитектурах процессоров и использовать препроцессор и макросы для переопределения архитектурно-зависимых типов данных.
3. Тут особо строгих критериев нет. Ваша программа потребляет немного ОЗУ, а тип процессора, по всей видимости, не принципиален, поэтому пишите навскидку. Если у вашей программы есть какие-нибудь ограничения по входным данным, то попробуйте ввести максимум и посмотреть, сколько ресурсов потребляет программа.

Comment: 1. Я использую только заголовочные файлы:   
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <locale.h>  
Т.е. везде всё верно будет работать?  
2. Т.е. мою программу с винды на убунту просто так не перенесёшь?   Данных там не так много. Максимальное число ~50000. Поэтому с интами можно не париться.  
3.Спасибо. Просто меня этот вопрос немного рассмешил.  
    
Благодарю.

Comment: 1. Это заголовки из стандартной библиотеки C, должно работать везде без дополнительных зависимостей.
 2. Ну, тут можно Wine использовать. Но это, наверное, не совсем то, что вам нужно. В общем случае, так сделать не получится.

Comment: @fori1ton, только сейчас надо скорее смотреть различную разрядность не **int**-ов (16-bit процессоры как-то уже отошли...), а **long**-ов.

Comment: Получается нельзя откомпилировать где-то в одной среде, что бы работало на всех ОС?

Comment: Нельзя, только компиляция на каждой из платформ поможет. Либо на Java писать. Либо веб приложение.

Comment: Подскажите, где лучше собрать программу, что бы на винде везед работала? MCVS люто не доверяю.

Comment: На "венде везде работала" - уточните формулировку. Что значит на "винде везде"? На всех версиях виндовс?

Comment: Накидайте библиотек от msvc рядом с исполняемым файлом